# Brackets display instead of space / out of a-z, 0-9, A-Z characters

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, special-characters

I have a issue of display square brackets instead of some spaces OR another characters which is out of `a-z, A-Z and 0-9.` Using `rails 3 with MySQL`.

```
Example: jalapeño
```

above string display but character 'ñ' display square brackets.

what actual problems does not find.

My create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE `venues` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_method` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Tablet Polling',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx1` (`latitude`),
  KEY `idx2` (`longitude`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: check utf support with your server

Comment: yes, utf support to my server

Comment: paste explain create table tale_name or type and attribute of table including char type

Comment: i updated question, you can see their